# Zip array of arrays to another array

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have an array

```
arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and I want to zip an array of arrays to it

```
arr2 = [[1, "foo"], [2, "bar"], [3, "baz"]]
```

so that the end result is

```
[["a", 1, "foo"], ["b", 2, "bar"], ["c", 3, "baz"]]
```

Right now what I'm doing is `arr1.zip(arr2).map!(&:flatten)`, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is an `each_index` iteration, then `inject` the element from arr1 into the element of arr2. If you find this helpful, I will post, but it seems longer than what you have now

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the way you're doing it, but an alternative might be `arr2.each_with_index{|a,i| a.unshift(arr1[i])}` ... but really, yours is nicer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another way is:

```
arr1.zip(*arr2.transpose)
# => [["a", 1, "foo"], ["b", 2, "bar"], ["c", 3, "baz"]]
```

Comment: That's a clever use of transpose.

Comment: This wouldn't work if `arr2` contains arrays with different sizes, isn't symmetric, doesn't work if both contain arrays of arrays and OP's solution is still clearer, but I have to admit that this is pretty clever.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two other (closely-related) ways:

```
enum = arr1.to_enum
arr2.map { |a| [enum.next].concat(a) }
  #=> [["a", 1, "foo"], ["b", 2, "bar"], ["c", 3, "baz"]]
```

or

```
arr1_cpy = arr1.dup
arr2.map { |a| [arr1_cpy.shift].concat(a) }
  #=> [["a", 1, "foo"], ["b", 2, "bar"], ["c", 3, "baz"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr2.each_with_index{ |el,i| el.unshift(arr1[i]) }
```

Maybe you like that better?

Comment: If you're doing an unshift you're mutating the object, so you don't really need the `map!` bit.  The original array will change regardless.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn good point, updated. Although Doguita's answer is way better.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the content of `arr2` to be before the content of `arr1`, you cannot use the `#transpose` trick. However, you can:

```rb
arr1.map.with_index { |el, i| [*arr2[i], el] }
# => [[1, "foo", "a"], [2, "bar", "b"], [3, "baz", "c"]]
```

Which has the perks of:

1. not mutating original arrays
2. let you choose the order

---

In terms of performance, Doguita's answer seems better:

```rb
arr1 = %w(foo) * 10_000
arr2 = arr1.length.times.map { |i| [i, i.to_s(2)] }
Benchmark.bmbm(20) do |x|
  x.report("zip & transpose:") { arr1.zip(*arr2.transpose) }
  x.report("map & with_index:") { arr1.map.with_index { |v, i| [v, *arr2[i]] } }
end
```

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------------------
zip & transpose:       0.000902   0.000233   0.001135 (  0.001107)
map & with_index:      0.004206   0.002308   0.006514 (  0.006828)
----------------------------------------------- total: 0.007649sec

                           user     system      total        real
zip & transpose:       0.001474   0.000045   0.001519 (  0.001471)
map & with_index:      0.002155   0.000059   0.002214 (  0.002282)
```